# Choice of discrete, non-monotonic response model

Tags: regression, logistic

Suppose I have data from coin-flip experiments done in differenet conditions X. I want to estimate P(X), the probability of getting heads.

What I would normaly do is try logistic regression, where I assume $P(X) = \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta (X-X_0)}}$, but in this case I know for sure that the probability is not monotnonic in X. In fact, I'm specifically looking for the value of X which maximizes P(X).

Is there a standard way of doing this, or do I have to make up my own model, such as $P(X) = \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta (X-X_0)^2}}$ ?

Comment: Can you give more details what X is? Exactly describing the problem would be best. If not, is it only a single variable or many? And is it binary, nominal, ordinal, count, number?

Comment: What you have decsribes is still a logistic regression, but one where the linear predictor is quadratic in $x$. You could also try a regression spline!